# Find city, state and country information from a location string in R

Tags: r, geolocation, stringr

I have a string vector with location information. Here is the part of my string

```
location_information = c("Hartville, Ohio","Malaysia,Johor Bahru","Culpeper, irginia",
                          "MD", "Atlanta","Granada Hills CA","Kansas City, mo")
```

With this string vector, I wanted to get the city, state, and country information. Here is the desired output for the sample.

```
desired_out = data.frame(  Country = c("US","Malaysia",rep("US",5)),
  State = c("Ohio",NA,"Virginia","Maryland","Georgia","California","Missouri"),
  City = c("Hartville","Johor Bahru","Culpeper",NA, "Atlanta","Granada Hills","Kansas City"))
```

How can I get that information with the consistent string format?

I think I may need to use Google API or something. How can I do it in R?

Comment: Note that your location vector contains locations in the US as well as Malaysia, yet this country information does not appear there.  You would have to do some kind of lookup to get the country.

Comment: Is there a lookup dictionary for Countries and Cities or you expect `R` to do the magic for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the geocoding from openstreetmap to get needed additional information.

Note that you (probably) will not be able to parse hunderds/thousands of locations in one go.

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(dplyr)
# sample data of locations
location_information = c("Hartville, Ohio","Malaysia,Johor Bahru","Culpeper, Virginia",
                         "MD", "Atlanta","Granada Hills CA","Kansas City, mo")
# geocode the locations
loc.data <- tmaptools::geocode_OSM(location_information, as.sf = TRUE)
# reverse geocode the locations for additional OSM data
tmaptools::rev_geocode_OSM(loc.data) %>%
  dplyr::select(country, state, city, town, village, city_district)
#         country      state        city     town   village city_district
# 1 United States       Ohio        <NA>     <NA> Hartville          <NA>
# 2      Malaysia      Johor Johor Bahru     <NA>      <NA>          <NA>
# 3 United States   Virginia        <NA> Culpeper      <NA>          <NA>
# 4 United States   Maryland        <NA>     <NA>      <NA>          <NA>
# 5 United States    Georgia     Atlanta     <NA>      <NA>          <NA>
# 6 United States California Los Angeles     <NA>      <NA> Granada Hills
# 7 United States   Missouri Kansas City     <NA>      <NA>          <NA>
```